# How to create category filter on a blog like on the site below?

Tags: categories, filters, blog

I want to create a blog with different categories of content and I would like the have a category filter on it. But I don't want to create different pages for it. I want the posts to just adjust according to which category I choose.

See ex: https://www.blumeglobal.com/resource-center/

I have tried different widgets but nothing great :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can have "Filter Posts By Category" plugin or pass your `category_name` (string) or  `cat` (int - category id ) in `WP_Query::query()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gutenberg Block Editor on WordPress, you can try the [Gutentor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutentor/) plugin and use Advanced Post (Type) Block.
You can check [Advanced Post (Type) Block demo](https://demo.gutentor.com/module-elements/advanced-post-module/).

You can **Filter the Post by Category** ( any post type with their taxonomy terms) and also add other options like pagination, navigation and load more button.